# SA1126: prefix required on base class methods, but not in all contexts

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have a base class (it's derived from `System.Web.UI.Page`)

It has two methods:

```
public static void LogError(string message, Exception exception) { ... }
public static string GetSupplierLogo(string supplierName) { ... }
```

In my derived class, I do this

```
this.uxLogoImage.ImageUrl = GetSupplierLogo("CompanyName");
```

and elsewhere in the same class

```
LogError("Exception...", ex);
```

Stylecop says: "SA1126: The call to GetSupplierLogo must begin with the 'this.', 'base.', 'object.' or 'MyClass.' prefix to indicate the intended method call.

But it says nothing about the call to LogError(). Why?

---

UPDATE
When the calls to either method are outside a catch block, stylecop is unhappy:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogError("Testing...", null);
}
```

But inside a catch, it's happy:

```
protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try { }
    catch()
    {
        LogError("Exception...", ex);
    }
}
```

Is it a bug, or is there is some reason for the difference?

Comment: Are both calls made in the same context? What happens if you add that `LogError()` call immediately after the `GetSupplierLogo()` call?

Comment: Interesting. When I did that, Stylecop complained about LogError(). I'll update my question with the contexts.

Comment: So, make it happy, it tells you what to do.  Never assume that the tool you have between your ears is inferior to a machine.

Comment: Heh, that is definitely odd. But Hans has good advice; since the solution is easy enough, just shut it up and hope that it provides better advice elsewhere. :)

Comment: It's not quite that easy since none of Stylecop's suggestions work. These are static methods so obviously `this` and `base` are out and the method isn't a member of `object` or `MyClass`. It is a member of `BaseClass` however, and that is the prefix I needed, so the cop has been silenced.

Comment: Update: This was a [bug in stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7372) and has been fixed in [stylecop 4.7.36 Aug 27](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/6de8910f02bd)